# Camel - how to limit file size for sftp consumer?

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp, spring-camel

I have dsl route:

```
from(String.format("sftp://%s@%s:%d/%s?password=%s&delete=true&readLock=changed&delay=%s",
                systemSettingsService.getSystemSettings().getSftpUserName(),
                systemSettingsService.getSystemSettings().getSftpHost(),
                systemSettingsService.getSystemSettings().getSftpPort(),
                systemSettingsService.getSystemSettings().getSftpSourcePathDestWorking(),
                systemSettingsService.getSystemSettings().getSftpPassword(),
                systemSettingsService.getSystemSettings().getSftpPollPeriod())).streamCaching()

                .process(...
```

I want to limit file size for consuming. For example I want to ignore files with size more than 100Mb. Optionally I want to have callback in case if camel met file more than 100mb

I have read:

http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html

But I could not find anything relevant

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a `filter`.

`from(String.format("sftp://%s@%s:%d/%s?filter=#myFilter",...`

Create a custom bean that implements the GenericFileFilter interface

```
import org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter;

public class MyFileFilter<T> implements GenericFileFilter<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {
        // I'm guessing the return value will be in bytes
        if (file.getFileLength() < (100 * 1024 * 1024))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Read more about it [here.](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) It's worth remembering that the FTP and SFTP components inherit from the File component.

Comment: How to rrgister the filter in camel infrastructure?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the Java DSL for Camel but after reading [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-beanintegration) it would seem that you can use the @BeanInject annotation as explained in the section named `Accessing a Spring bean from Java`